# Codeigniter, Passing a variable from a model to a controller

Tags: codeigniter, variables, model, controller

New to Codeigniter & PHP.

I would like to retrieve a single bit data from a database, turn that single bit of data into a variable and pass it to the controller and use that data as a single variable? For example I could do a if $string=$string and so on, with the data in the controller.

If anyone could produce an example of a model and controller it would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Mark this answer as "ACCEPTED", poster! :)

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty straightforward and [taken right from CodeIgniter's documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/), which you should definitely read through (comments in the code are mostly mine):

**The Controller**

```
class Blog_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function blog()
    {
        // Load the Blog model so we can get some data
        $this->load->model('Blog');

        // Call "get_last_ten_entries" function and assign its result to a variable
        $data['query'] = $this->Blog->get_last_ten_entries();

        // Load view and pass our variable to display data to the user
        $this->load->view('blog', $data);
    }
}
```

**The Model**

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model {

    var $title   = '';
    var $content = '';
    var $date    = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // Query the database to get some data and return the result
    function get_last_ten_entries()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('entries', 10);
        return $query->result();
    }

    // ... truncated for brevity

}
```

**Edit**

This is pretty basic stuff and I highly recommend simply [reading through the documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) and [walking through some tutorials](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/), but I'll try to help anyway:

Based on your comment below, you want the following (which, admittedly, is pretty vague):

1. get a single bit of data out of the query
2. pass that to a variable (do you mean "assign that to a variable"?)
3. validate that bit of data from the database

Please read over the [Database class documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html). This really depends on the specific query you're running and what data you want from it. Based on the above example, it might look something like this in some function in your model (Keep in mind this is completely arbitrary as I have no idea what your query looks like or what data you want):

```
// Get a single entry record
$query = $this->db->get('entries', 1);

// Did the query return a single record?
if($query->num_rows() === 1){

    // It returned a result
    // Get a single value from the record and assign it to a variable
    $your_variable = $this->query()->row()->SOME_VALUE_FROM_RETURNED_RECORD;

    // "Validate" the variable.
    // This is incredibly vague, but you do whatever you want with the value here
    // e.g. pass it to some "validator" function, return it to the controller, etc.
    if($your_variable == $some_other_value){
        // It validated!
    } else {
        // It did not validate
    }

} else {
    // It did not return any results
}
```

Comment: Thank you Colin for your help. Just trying to explain this a bit deeper. I wanted to get a single bit of data out of the query and pass that to a variable not to use it to pass it to a view but to validate that bit of data from the database. so... Get single bit of data from database check if $data = $data..

Comment: Thank you, most appreciated. Very helpful.